# Android make home phone

Tags: android

When I give number="05338830967"; is like it is working but when I give this number number="03926502323"; it is not running, phone tell me that create internet call what is it?

```
    private void makePhoneCall(String number) {
      try {

          for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {
                if ( number.contains("-")) {
                 String[] numaraduzelt = number.split("-");  
                 number= numaraduzelt[0]+numaraduzelt[1];
                }
            }
            number="tel:+9"+number;

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(number));
                 }
                  }
```

Comment: Are you sure your number is correct?

Comment: just type +903926502323 in your phone's dialpad, make call and see if it is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the excellent [libphonenumber](http://libphonenumber.googlecode.com) library from Google that is being used everywhere including the Android framework for parsing and formatting phone numbers.  This would allow you to validate the phone number before you attempt to send a dialing Intent.